# Workflow and source layout for large javascript library

Tags: javascript, project

I'm about to develop a large javascript library, and am wondering what the best workflow / source tree layout is. The end result will be a single, minified javascript file.

Suppose the library looks something like:

```
/
    src/
        main.js
        folder1/
            file1.js
            file2.js
            file3.js
        folder2/
            f1.js
            f2.js
    build/
    docs/
    tests/
```

How do I debug this? Is the answer as simple as "*import all the js via script tags in an html file*?" I **REALLY** don't want to do that, but if that's what everybody else is doing... I was thinking require.js would work well, but then I'd have to be sure to rip out everything that uses require.js when I build (concatenate the files, use uglify.js/closure/etc).

Basically I've never worked on a javascript library before that I didn't need to split into more than a handful of files. I've never had to create a build process for my javascript code.

Am I doing this right? How would one have modules that don't or shouldn't be built into the main, minified file (eg, the developer can optionally include them)?

How do large javascript libraries intended for a browser run automated tests?

*Stackoverflow seems like the best place to ask this question, even if it is open ended and rather subjective.*

Comment: google "javascript library boilerplate"

Comment: require.js comes with r.js (a pretty rad optimizer imho) if this is the only thing keeping you from using require.js http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html - second option would be using usemin: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin

Comment: this article may be helpful: http://flippinawesome.org/2013/07/01/building-a-javascript-library-with-grunt-js/